MAUI IOS not working properly on Release mode
I have MAUI app and there are some problems at Release mode. The app is working properly at Debug mode but when i switched to Release mode deserialization is not working (using Newtonsoft).
This is one of my methods where on debug everything is okay
public async Task<AuthenticationResultModel> Login(string email, string password, HttpClient client)
{
    var req = new LoginRequestModel();
    req.Email = email;
    req.Password = password;

    var url = _baseUrl + GlobalConstants.LoginUrl;
    var result = new AuthenticationResultModel();
    
    try
    {
        using (client)
        {
            StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req), Encoding.UTF8, GlobalConstants.JsonType);

            using (var response = await client.PostAsync(url, content))
            {
                string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthenticationResultModel>(apiResponse);
                    if (result.Code == 1)
                    {
                        return result;
                    }
                    else // Error
                    {
                        return result;
                    }
                }
                else // Error
                {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return result;
        throw;
    }

}

 

If I want deserialization to work on Release build i should add the following after initialization of result model
    result.Jwt = string.Empty;
    result.Code = 0;

The other problem is that Command binding is not working at Release mode. When i am using Debug mode there is no problem.
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:handlers="clr-namespace:WTO.MobileApp.Handlers"
             x:Class="WTO.MobileApp.Views.Pages.LoginPage"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
             Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Flyout"
             BackgroundColor="White"
             Title="LoginPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <handlers:BoolToColorConverter x:Key="BoolToColorConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <ScrollView>
        <Grid>
            <Grid RowDefinitions="*, 8*">
                <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="wtologo.png"
               Aspect="AspectFit"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               HeightRequest="{OnPlatform iOS='50'}"
               Margin="30,0,30,0"/>
                <!-- Background Image -->
                <Image Grid.Row="1" Source="asset.png"
               Aspect="AspectFit"         
               MaximumHeightRequest="400"
               Margin="0,30"
               VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
               HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
               Opacity="0.06"/>
            </Grid>

            <!-- Sign-In Form -->
            <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <!-- Centered Header -->
                <Label Text="Sign in"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               FontSize="30"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               FontFamily="Poppins"
               TextColor="{StaticResource Tertiary}"
               Margin="0"/>

                <!-- Email Entry -->
                <Grid Margin="0,40,0,20">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0"
                       Text="Email"
                       HorizontalOptions="Start"
                       FontSize="Small"
                       FontFamily="Poppins"
                       TextColor="#007597"
                       Margin="20,0,0,5"/>
                    <Frame Grid.Row="1"
                       BorderColor="{Binding EmailError, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}"
                       CornerRadius="4"
                       Padding="0"
                       BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                       Margin="20,0,20,0">
                        <VerticalStackLayout>
                            <Entry x:Name="EmailEntry" Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                   Placeholder="alex123@gmail.com"
                                   PlaceholderColor="#C1B5B5"
                                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                   TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start"
                                   Keyboard="Email" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                   IsPassword="False" Text="{Binding Email}">
                            </Entry>
                        </VerticalStackLayout>
                        <Frame.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger TargetType="Frame" Binding="{Binding IsError}" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Red" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Frame.Triggers>
                    </Frame>
                </Grid>

                <!-- Password Entry -->
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,20">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Row="0"
                       Text="Password"
                       HorizontalOptions="Start"
                       FontSize="Small"
                       FontFamily="Poppins"
                       TextColor="{StaticResource Tertiary}"
                       Margin="20,0,0,5"/>
                    <Frame Grid.Row="1"
                       BorderColor="{Binding PasswordError, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}"
                       CornerRadius="4"
                       Padding="0" 
                       BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                       Margin="20,0,20,0">
                        <Grid>
                            <Entry x:Name="PasswordEntry"
                                   Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                   TextColor="Black"
                                   Text="{Binding Password}"
                                   Placeholder="*********"
                                   IsPassword="true"
                                   PlaceholderColor="#C1B5B5"
                                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

                            <ImageButton Source="hide.png"
                                     Clicked="TogglePasswordVisibility"
                                     WidthRequest="20"
                                     Scale="{OnPlatform iOS='0.6'}"
                                     HeightRequest="20"
                                     VerticalOptions="Center"
                                     HorizontalOptions="End"
                                     Margin="{OnPlatform Android='10'}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Frame>
                </Grid>

                <!-- Sign-In Button -->
                <Button Text="Sign in"
                    Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"
                    Margin="20"
                    Padding="30,10,30,10"
                    FontSize="Medium"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                    TextColor="White"
                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*" RowDefinitions="*" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="20,10,20,0">
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="New customer? " VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="Black"/>
                    <Button Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="Create an account" Command="{Binding GoToRegisterPageCommand}" TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}" FontAttributes="Bold" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Padding="1"/>
                </Grid>
                <Label Text="Forgot password?" 
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                   TextDecorations="Underline"
                   FontSize="Small" 
                   TextColor="{StaticResource Primary}" 
                   FontAttributes="Bold"
                   Margin="20,10,20,0">
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding GoToForgotPassPageCommand}"/>
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>

     [RelayCommand]
 private async Task Login()
 {
     try
     {
         if (IsBusy)
         {
             return;
         }
         IsBusy = true;

         ShowLoading();
         
         //do something

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {

         isValid = false;
         await App.DisplayAlert(App.MESSAGE_HEADER_ERROR, ex.Message, App.MESSAGE_OK);
     }
     finally
     {
         HideLoading();
         IsBusy = false;
        
     }
 }


If i want commands to work on Release i should set commands to some variables in page constructor, but its not okay
    public LoginPage(LoginPageViewModel vm)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    vm.Navigation = Navigation;
    this.BindingContext = vm;
    this.viewModel = vm;
    PasswordEntry.IsPassword = true;
    
    var a = viewModel.LoginCommand;
    var b = viewModel.GoToRegisterPageCommand;
    var c = viewModel.GoToForgotPassPageCommand;
}


Do not post code as images.

Can you share the complete xaml? Have you tried setting x:datatype to view model in your page. Also are you sure the method is being called and not exiting early.
For the first issue, highly recommend the system.text.json out of the support instead of any other nuget

you are catching an exception but then doing nothing with that data - there may be valuable information in the exception object

What .NET version and platform do you use?  And have you tested on a physical device?

I am using .NET 8 and these problems are only on IOS. Yes, it is tested on physical device.

Command binding issue cannot be reproduced on my side. Have you tried creating a new project and simplifying the UI?
